# unterminated string literal without breaking the line

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error: *SyntaxError: unterminated string literal.*
Seems like there is a problem with the first `data +=` command. What is wrong with it? I don't break any line.

```
        // Data
        var data = "<!doctype html><html><head>";
        data += "<script type='text/javascript' src='test1.js'></script>";
        data += "</head><body>TEST</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include the sequence of characters `</script>` in a script block. The HTML parser assumes that it ends the block.

The typical way of handling that is something like

```
    data += "<script type='text/javascript' src='test1.js'></" + "script>";
```

The HTML parser does not understand JavaScript syntax. When it sees `<script>`, it just does a blind search through subsequent content looking for `</script>`.

Comment: You're right, adding it like you described it solved the problem. But now the parser executes the JavaScript even if it is inside a string, e.g.  `data += '<scrip'+'t type="text/javascript">console.log("Inline");<'+'/script>';`. "Inline" will appear in the console

Comment: @user3631654 That's how `<script>` tags work, right? When the HTML parser parses a `<script>` block with inline content, it evaluates the JavaScript before continuing through the document.

Comment: But it is inside a string! that makes no sense. I also splitted the `<script>`-tag!?

Comment: Maybe you know also a solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411562/ie-executes-inline-scripts-before-external-in-dynamic-iframe-content